# Write function to find random value from given array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am new at PHP and struggling with given problem.

I have to write a `function winner_generator($parameter, $random)` that would pick and show random name from given array:

```
   <p><?php echo winner_generator(array(
        array('name' => 'Bob'),
        array('name' => 'Donald'),
        array('name' => 'Peter'),
        array('name' => 'Nick')
    ),rand()); ?></p>
```

Any ideas on how I should start solving this problem? Many thanks for all your help, looking forward.

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/517d490a69b9957f1c003c75

Comment: Create a random number between 0 and count($argarray) - 1 inclusive, and then use the element at position $argarray[$rndValue]. <br> Useful links: 
[Random in PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Comment: Remember that on SO you should also show what you have already tried. We are not here to write the code for you, we are here to help you spot the errors or the misconceptions behind your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea is generating a random number between 0 and the length of the array - 1 (because the index of an array starts at 0). Then you pick the candidate at whatever number the random returns. As you want to echo the winner you need to select the 'name' key from the candidate array.

```
<?php

function winner_generator(array $candidates){
    $rand = rand(0, sizeof($candidates)-1);
    return($candidates[$rand]['name']);
}

echo winner_generator(array(
    array('name' => 'Bob'),
    array('name' => 'Donald'),
    array('name' => 'Peter'),
    array('name' => 'Nick')
));
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: You are indees correct let me edit my response